# how to combine charts and TableView to be outputted as image png format?

Tags: java, charts, javafx, png, tableview

i have this 2 fully working  separated code for the same purpose i want to  combine together and be able to output the values in the same png file format .
See the image http://postimg.org/image/wtszfwq77/

first code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import java

fx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class TableViewSample2 extends Application {

    private TableView<Metric> table = new TableView<Metric>();

    private final ObservableList<Metric> data =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Metric("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"),
                 new Metric("2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2"),
                  new Metric("3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3"),
                   new Metric("4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4"),
                    new Metric("5","5","6","6","5","5","5","5")


        );


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
    stage.setTitle("Result of Java Metrics Analysis");
    stage.setWidth(700);
    stage.setHeight(500);

    final Label label = new Label("Result of Java Metrics Analysis");
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

    table.setEditable(true);



    // WMCCol,DITCol,NOCCol,CBOCol,RFCCol,LCOMCol,CaCol,NPMCol
    TableColumn WMCCol = new TableColumn("WMC");
    WMCCol.setMinWidth(100);
    WMCCol.setCellValueFactory(          new PropertyValueFactory<Metric, String>("WMC"));

    TableColumn DITCol = new TableColumn("DIT");
    DITCol.setMinWidth(100);
    DITCol.setCellValueFactory(        new PropertyValueFactory<Metric, String>("DIT"));

    TableColumn NOCCol = new TableColumn("NOC");
    NOCCol.setMinWidth(200);
    NOCCol.setCellValueFactory(             new PropertyValueFactory<Metric, String>("NOC"));


    TableColumn CBOCol = new TableColumn("CBO");
    CBOCol.setMinWidth(100);
    CBOCol.setCellValueFactory(          new PropertyValueFactory<Metric, String>("CBO"));

    TableColumn RFCCol = new TableColumn("RFC");
    RFCCol.setMinWidth(100);
    RFCCol.setCellValueFactory(        new PropertyValueFactory<Metric, String>("RFC"));

    TableColumn LCOMCol = new TableColumn("LCOM");
    LCOMCol.setMinWidth(200);
    LCOMCol.setCellValueFactory(             new PropertyValueFactory<Metric, String>("LCOM"));



    TableColumn CaCol = new TableColumn("Ca");
    CaCol.setMinWidth(100);
    CaCol.setCellValueFactory(          new PropertyValueFactory<Metric, String>("Ca"));

    TableColumn NPMCol = new TableColumn("NPM");
    NPMCol.setMinWidth(100);
    NPMCol.setCellValueFactory(        new PropertyValueFactory<Metric, String>("NPM"));




    table.setItems(data);
    table.getColumns().addAll(WMCCol,DITCol,NOCCol,CBOCol,RFCCol,LCOMCol,CaCol,NPMCol);

    final VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setSpacing(5);
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table);

    ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();


     WritableImage image = table.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);

// TODO: probably use a file chooser here
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\acer\\Desktop\\tableChart.png");

try {
    ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null), "png", file);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO: handle exception here
}


}

public static class Metric {

    private final SimpleStringProperty WMC;
    private final SimpleStringProperty DIT;
    private final SimpleStringProperty NOC;

    private final SimpleStringProperty CBO;
    private final SimpleStringProperty RFC;
    private final SimpleStringProperty LCOM;  

    private final SimpleStringProperty Ca;
    private final SimpleStringProperty NPM;



    private Metric(String vWMC,String vDIT, String vNOC, String vCBO,String vRFC,String vLCOM, String vCa, String vNPM) {


        //
        this.WMC = new SimpleStringProperty(vWMC);
        this.DIT = new SimpleStringProperty(vDIT);
        this.NOC = new SimpleStringProperty(vNOC);

        this.CBO = new SimpleStringProperty(vCBO);
        this.RFC = new SimpleStringProperty(vRFC);
        this.LCOM = new SimpleStringProperty(vLCOM);

        this.Ca = new SimpleStringProperty(vCa);
        this.NPM = new SimpleStringProperty(vNPM);

    }


    public String getWMC() {            return WMC.get();  }
    public void setWMC(String vWMC) {     WMC.set(vWMC); }

    public String getDIT() {            return DIT.get();     }
    public void setDIT(String vDIT) {       DIT.set(vDIT);   }

    public String getNOC() {        return NOC.get();       }
    public void setNOC(String vNOC) {   NOC.set(vNOC);    }


    public String getCBO() {            return CBO.get();  }
    public void setCBO(String vCBO) {     CBO.set(vCBO); }

    public String getRFC() {            return RFC.get();     }
    public void setRFC(String vRFC) {       RFC.set(vRFC);   }

    public String getLCOM() {        return LCOM.get();       }
    public void setLCOM(String vLCOM) {   LCOM.set(vLCOM);    }


    public String getCa() {            return Ca.get();  }
    public void setCa(String vCa) {     Ca.set(vCa); }

    public String getNPM() {            return NPM.get();     }
    public void setNPM(String vNPM) {       NPM.set(vNPM);   }





    }
}
```

second code

```
package javaapplication12;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class JavaFX_Charts extends Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Result of Java Metrics Analysis");
        Group root = new Group();

        ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = 
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new PieChart.Data("WMC", 100),
                    new PieChart.Data("DIT", 200),
                    new PieChart.Data("NOC", 50),
                    new PieChart.Data("CBO", 75),
                    new PieChart.Data("RFC", 110),
                    new PieChart.Data("LCOM", 300),
                    new PieChart.Data("Ca", 111),
                    new PieChart.Data("NPM", 30)

                );

        final PieChart pieChart = new PieChart(pieChartData);
        pieChart.setTitle("RESULT");

        root.getChildren().add(pieChart);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 400));

        primaryStage.show();


                    WritableImage image = pieChart.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);

                    // TODO: probably use a file chooser here
                    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\acer\\Desktop\\pieChart.png");

                    try {
                        ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null), "png", file);

                       }   catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception here
                    }







}


    }
```

Comment: There is no [JTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) in your code and it would be inadvisable to use one for your application as mixing JavaFX and Swing UI toolkits is not recommended for small applications such as yours.

Answer (score 1):

Put both the JavaFX chart and the TableView in the same scene within a single application and [snapshot the entire scene](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#snapshot-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-) rather than just the pie chart.